# Navigation bar + Search controller + Large title: Hairline during scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

Context:

- `UINavigationController` with a `UITableViewController`
- `UISearchController` in the navigation bar
- Navigation bar translucent with black style, it uses large title, `tintColor`, `barTintColor` (so no background image).

Issue:

I have a strange animation glitch that shows a hairline above the search bar. The hairline appears only during the scroll.

[image: Screencast]

I have already tried many solutions concerning similar problems, but they have not helped.

Tested with an iPhone 7 with iOS 12.1.3

Answer (score -1):

You can fix hairline issue using this

```
searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 242/255.0, green: 82/255.0, blue: 46/255.0, alpha: 1).CGColor
searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

if the above didn’t work. you can remove the hairline completely

```
extension UINavigationBar {
        func hideBottomHairline() {
            self.hairlineImageView?.isHidden = true
        }

        func showBottomHairline() {
            self.hairlineImageView?.isHidden = false
        }
    }

extension UIView {
    fileprivate var hairlineImageView: UIImageView? {
        return hairlineImageView(in: self)
    }

    fileprivate func hairlineImageView(in view: UIView) -> UIImageView? {
        if let imageView = view as? UIImageView, imageView.bounds.height <= 1.0 {
            return imageView
        }

        for subview in view.subviews {
            if let imageView = self.hairlineImageView(in: subview) { return imageView }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all I'm using `UISearchController` instead of `UISearchDisplayController`, in any case, thanks but it does not help. Furthermore, what is the `self.hairlineImageView` property?

Comment: Search bar border does not help because the hairline appears above, please open https://duaw26jehqd4r.cloudfront.net/items/3y1p3j252B1Z3912422V/IMG_3044-2.png

Image view `hairlineImageView` is found and hidden, but the problem remains.

The only way so far observed to not have the problem is to set the navigation bar as opaque.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355288/change-navigation-bar-bottom-border-color-swift
for the least solution, you can try change that bottom hairline color.