# Flicker during transition when Search bar (within Large Title Navigation Bar) tapped - Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have added search bar in navigation bar large title. I am facing a flicker issue when the search bar is tapped to type into it.

Here is the video to the explain the issue:

[image]

The code I have written to achieve this is:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.title = "Leads"
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addNewLeadsAction(_:)))
        let mysearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        mysearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        mysearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Lead"
        mysearchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        mysearchController.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        mysearchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: Common.gradientImage(view: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar)!))
        if let textfield = mysearchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            textfield.textColor = UIColor.white
            if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {
                backgroundview.backgroundColor = .white
                backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true
            }
        }
        for searchBarView in mysearchController.searchBar.subviews{
            for cancelButtonView in searchBarView.subviews{
                if cancelButtonView.isKind(of: UIButton.self) {
                    let filterButton:UIButton = cancelButtonView as! UIButton
                    filterButton.isEnabled = true
                    filterButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
                    let image1 = UIImage(named: "filterIcon")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                    filterButton.setImage(image1, for: .normal)
                    filterButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                    filterButton.tintColor = .white
                    filterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(filterAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                }
            }
        }
        self.navigationItem.searchController = mysearchController
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        leadsTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Trying to make the transition smooth is what i'm looking to achieve.
Following are the things I have tried already:

[iOS 11 UISearchBar in UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997996/ios-11-uisearchbar-in-uinavigationbar/46770778)

[Navigation bar + Search controller + Large title: Hairline during scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504586/navigation-bar-search-controller-large-title-hairline-during-scrolling)

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Maybe you can fix this issue by changing the background color of view or window, And set the color as your search bar background color.

Comment: If i set background color to view, I still see the black coming along with the color

Comment: Did you ever find an elegant solution to this?